# how to send a push notification to single user in BB 10 cascades

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have integrated PushCollector App to my app for pushnotifications  and also hard coded the PPG URL, APP ID User ID and Password etc in my App.

Now my question is how to send the push notification to single user rather than all users at a time.I found the PIN is used for this purpose. what is this pin? Is this what we see System Settings->about->category Hardware->Pin?

I am new to BB 10 and it's Platform features and looking for guidelines like from this forum

Please help,

Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is [documentation for Push](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_comm/push/) on the BlackBerry Developer Site under the Device Communication section.

Also, you can look at [BlackBerry's Cascades pushCollector sample project on GitHub](https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/master/pushCollector) for more examples.